# Many to many relationship inserts

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, many-to-many

I have two classes, for instance:

```
class A {
    public virtual ICollection<B> BList { get; set; }
}

class B {
    public virtual ICollection<A> AList { get; set; }
}
```

Entity Framework then creates A and B tables and AB table that connects them.

In my application I get `A_ID` and `B_ID`, and I need to make connection between A and B.

What I did is fetch A by ID, then fetch B by ID, and then do `A.BList.Add(BObject)`, but that is 3 database trips, 2 fetches + one insert.

Is there any way in Entity Framework to do it in one database trip?

UPDATE:

I looked at the link Martin provided, and wrote a simple example:

```
User user = new User { ID = 12135 };
Book book = new Book { ID = 1};

context.Users.Attach(user);
context.Books.Attach(book);

user.Books.Add(book);  

context.SaveChanges();
```

But I got null pointer exception at `user.Books.Add(book);` `user.Books` is null, and it throws exception when Add is called...

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478570/entity-framework-code-first-adding-to-many-to-many-relationship-by-id) link shows a solution using just one ( the insert) roundtrip.

Comment: I just looked at the link myself ! what a twisted but logic way, honnestly i wasen't suspecting a thing like that to work, incredible.

Comment: @Aleksa does the name of the primary key of these table is really named "ID" in your case ?

Comment: Yes, ID is the primary key for both classes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialize your collection navigation properties in the entity's constructors:

```
public class A {
    public A()
    { 
       BList=new List<B>();
    }
    public virtual ICollection<B> BList { get; set; }
}
```

Do the same with the `B` entity.

Also you don't need to attach the new entities at the beginning, to save them you can do this:

```
  User user = new User { ID = 12135 };
  Book book = new Book { ID = 1};

  user.Books.Add(book);  
  context.Users.Add(user);
  context.SaveChanges();
```

That's going to insert the three rows in just one database trip

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can resume your code and try this:

```
User user = new User { 
                       ID = 12135 , 
                       Books = new ICollection<Book>() { new Book { ID = 1} } 
                     };

context.Users.Attach(user);
```

Or:

```
User user = new User { ID = 12135 };
Book book = new Book { ID = 1};

context.Users.Attach(user);
context.Books.Attach(book);

user.Books = new ICollection<Book>();

user.Books.Add(book);
```

To resolve null pointer expection need to add a **initializer to Books** user collection, in code or in the **User class constructor**.